# Which port is used to access another Pod on the same Cluster? Port, NodePort or TargetPort

Tags: kubernetes

I have created 2 pods within the same cluster. One service is initialized as

```
kubectl create deployment my-web --image=nginx --port=80
kubectl expose deployment my-web --target-port=80 --type=NodePort
```

to my understanding, this creates a deployment with one pod `my-web-<string>` and exposes a port. With `kubectl describe services my-web`, I find that the following information:

```
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32004/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.10:80
```

testing pod:

```
kubectl run test-pod --image=nginx --restart=Never
```

this creates another pod and I try to curl the nginx of my-web pod with the command `curl 10.244.0.10:32004`. That request times out. But somehow it works when I use `curl 10.244.0:80`. Why is that? I thought the service was exposed on port 32004 outside the my-web pod?

Please also let me know what IP and port to curl from my host machine to access the my-web pod. I am running the cluster from minikube on MacOS.

Thanks for the help!

I try to curl the nginx of my-web pod with the command `curl 10.244.0.10:32004`. That request times out. But somehow it works when I use `curl 10.244.0:80`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodePort is used to access a service within the cluster scope.
You might create a firewall rule that allows TCP traffic on your node port. Create a firewall rule that allows TCP traffic on port 32004.
On Ubuntu you can do something like:

> sudo ufw allow 32004/tcp

And check port status with:

> sudo ufw status

Once you are sure the port is opened you can curl the ip:port

```
curl http://10.244.0.10:32004
```

For further info check the [Kubernetes official documentation.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/)

Comment: have you checked the firewall ? see the answer :)

Comment: checked now. thanks for the help

Comment: glad to help somehow